# Is there a concept name for a regular type for which comparisons doesn't compare the full object state?

Tags: c++, c++11, concept, c++-concepts

I have a set of types which looks like this:

```
struct MyFlag
{
     SomeId source_id; // INVALID_ID by default
     SomeData data; // regular type

     friend bool operator==( const MyFlag& a, const MyFlag& b ) { return a.source_id == b.source_id; }
     friend bool operator<( const MyFlag& a, const MyFlag& b ) { return a.source_id < b.source_id; }
     friend bool operator!=( const MyFlag& a, const MyFlag& b ) { return !(a == b); }

     friend bool operator==( const SomeId& a, const MyFlag& b ) { return a == b.source_id; }
     friend bool operator<( const SomeId& a, const MyFlag& b ) { return a < b.source_id; }
};



MyFlag flag_a { id, data_A };
MyFlag flag_b { id, data_B };

assert( flag_a == flag_b );
assert( flag_a.data != flag_b.data );
assert( flag_a == id );
assert( flag_b == id ); 

MyFlag flag = flag_b;
assert( flag == flag_a );
assert( flag == id );
assert( flag.data != flag_a.data );

const MyFlag flag_x ={ id_x, data_A };
flag = flag_X;
assert( flag != flag_a );
assert( flag.data == flag_a.data );
```

That is, only a specific part of the state of the object is considered in comparison: in this example, any MyFlag object would be compared to others using their ids, but not the rest of the data they contain.

I think it match the definition Sean Parent gave of a "value type", but I also think this is a strange or unfamiliar (but useful in my case) pattern.

So my question is: is there a concept name for this ... concept?

---

How is that kind of type useful? I use this kind of type in a "black board" event system which is basically a kind of set of any value that have a type that is at least regular.
However, this black board systematically overwrite the value pushed (inserted) in it even if it's already found (through comparison). That way, I overwrite the full state of a value in the black board using the comparison operators as identifiers.

I have no idea if it's a well known pattern or idea or if it's problematic on the long run. So far it have been very useful. It also feels like something that might be "too smart", but I lack experience with this pattern to confirm that. It might be that I am abusing the use of comparison operators, but it feels that the semantic of these types is correct in my use.

I can provide a detailed example of my usage if necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure what the relation is to C++ Concepts.

Comment: You mean the language feature? Well it's a language implementation of "concepts" as they are defined in the standard or in libraries, so I expect experts in library-defined concept to know if there is a known concept name for this thing, which looks like "Regular" but I don't think that's correct but I'm not knowledgeable enough.

Comment: If I follow this document: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3351.pdf , in particular page 54 definition of SemiRegular and Regular, I think what I'm doing is a Regular type, but it feels like it might need another concept name as it's not exactly that.

Comment: Ah, maybe via axioms. As far as I understood Concepts (or Constraints), they're more about *can this type* (abilities) than semantics. I.e. your type has all abilities of a RegularType, but as opposed to, say `int`, the semantics of comparison are different. Namely, there exist two objects comparing equal that have different behaviour (different `.data`) / that are not interchangeable.

Comment: Your type is not EqualityComparable: your `==` returns true for objects with distinct values. The definition of EqualityComparable in §3.3 includes `axiom { a == b <=> eq(a, b); }`.

Comment: @Casey What if `SomeData` has no `operator==`? I mean, how is `eq` defined? (3.1.1 "Returns true if and only if a and b are equal according to the strongest available interpretation of equality for type T")

Comment: @Casey the problem is that "distinct values" doesn't always include implementation details. What if I have such a type, with some mutable values that count the access to the data which are accessed through "getters"? In this case the state of the object have both it's value and additional meta data.

Comment: Also, Sean Parent and others in their recent C++ talks talked about value as being the perceived value from outside, not the implementation details. The problem here is that I am not sure if this type's value is only the compared data or more than the compared data it contain.

Answer (score 2):

`MyFlag` is not `EqualityComparable`, since `==` returns true for objects with distinct values. The definition of `EqualityComparable` in §3.3 includes `axiom { a == b <=> eq(a, b); }`.

Informally, `eq` is meant to represent equality of what we would consider to be the *value* of an object regardless of the existence of an `==` for that object's type. This isn't strictly the same thing as representational equality, since (a) different representations can be considered equal (e.g., `-0.0 == 0.0`), and (b) there can be insignificant state in representations (colloquially "padding").

In the case of `MyFlag`, I find it almost certain that `data` would be considered significant in the value of a `MyFlag` in some context (several occurrences appear in the OP itself). Formally, I could define an operator `cmp` over `MyFlag` as:

```
bool cmp(const MyFlag& a, const MyFlag& b) {
  return a == b && a.data == b.data;
}
```

which clearly provides a stronger interpretation of equality than the corresponding `operator ==`.

Consider an implementation of `std::copy`:

```
template <typename In, typename Out>
Out copy_(In first, In last, Out out, std::false_type) {
  while(first != last) {
    *out++ = *first++;
  }
}

template <typename In, typename Out>
Out copy_(In first, In last, Out out, std::true_type) {
  while(first != last) {
    *out = *first;
    *out.data = SomeData();
    ++first;
    ++out;
  }
}

template <typename In, typename Out>
Out copy(In first, In last, Out out) {
  copy_(first, last, out, std::is_same<
          Myflag,
          typename std::iterator_traits<In>::value_type>());
}
```

Would you consider this to be a valid implementation of `copy`, or would you say it is corrupting data? It is equality-preserving according to `Myflag`'s `operator ==`.

Contrastingly, had `Myflag` been defined as:

```
class MyFlag
{
     SomeData trash_bits;
public:
     SomeId source_id; // INVALID_ID by default

     friend bool operator==( const MyFlag& a, const MyFlag& b ) { return a.source_id == b.source_id; }
     friend bool operator<( const MyFlag& a, const MyFlag& b ) { return a.source_id < b.source_id; }
     friend bool operator!=( const MyFlag& a, const MyFlag& b ) { return !(a == b); }

     friend bool operator==( const SomeId& a, const MyFlag& b ) { return a == b.source_id; }
     friend bool operator<( const SomeId& a, const MyFlag& b ) { return a < b.source_id; }
};
```

you could make a compelling argument that `trash_bits` are not part of the value of a `MyFlag` since they are never observed. *Then* I would agree that `MyFlag` is `Regular`.

Comment: the problem is that "distinct values" doesn't always include implementation details. What if I have such a type, with some mutable values that count the access to the data which are accessed through "getters"? In this case the state of the object have both it's value and additional meta data.

Comment: Do you mean it depends also on the usage, therefore on the axiom?

Comment: @Klaim Yes, the semantics depend on usage. If there exists a function `f` in the program such that `f(a) != f(b)`, then necessarily `!eq(a, b)`. Since `data` is exposed as a public member of `MyFlag`, it is necessarily part of the value: anyone can write a function that examines `data` and can therefore discriminate two supposedly equal values.

Comment: Nit-pick: `SomeData` could be empty and other pathological cases. Other than that, +1 (I think the characterization of equivalence according to observable behaviour is important).

Comment: (just to complete comments here) In my use cases, the blackboard container I push these types in actually can be enums, some custom int-like values and some types which works as MyFlag. What I wanted was a generic way to identify a copy of an object as being a copy of that object without having to defined an identifier type, which would prevent me from using, for example, enums, which I use when I just need to check that the value have been pushed or not.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might find the answer in [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2479.pdf) from John Lakos, specificly in the background section. In short Lakos distinguishes the *salient attributes* which make up the value of an object vs. the *non-salient attributes* (I remember them being called *incidental attributes*, too but might be wrong about that) that do not (like e.g. the capacity of a vector).

Answer (score 1):

The type has correct comparison operators defining a total ordering and is therefore `TotallyOrdered` (using the [N3351](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3351.pdf) definition).

That does not distinguish whether the total ordering compares all of the object state or not, but there does not seem to be any concept for differentiating that. Because it would neither be possible to define (the `==` says the objects are equal based on the compared part of the state, how can you tell whether there is also any uncompared part?) nor does any algorithm reason to care.

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be describing is a non-essential part. It is very similar to capacity() on an std::vector. The concept of Regular is defined in terms of the semantics of copy, assignment, and equality. So long as those semantics are obeyed, your type is Regular. You need to decide what the essential part of you type are by deciding what it is that the type represents. The essential parts, those that contribute to what the object represents, must be copies and included in equality comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should distinguish between the level at which you apply your relational operators and their semantics. Your operators seem to have the correct semantics, but are applied at a confusing level (ID member, rather than the whole object).

First, I would define `operator==` and `operator<` to **compare the entire object state**. This is the least surprising and most idiomatic way. To only compare ids, just make a **named operator** `id_equal_to` that does a projection onto the ID data member. If you like, you can even define mixed versions (taking one `MyFlag` and one `SomeID` parameter), but that is usually only necessary to avoid overhead of implicit conversions. It doesn't seem required in this case.

Second, to make sure that these operators have the **correct semantics** (reflexive, symmetric and transitive for `operator==`, and irreflexive, asymmetric, transitive and total for `operator<`), just define them in terms of `std::tie` and the corresponding operator for `std::tuple`. You should also make sure that `operator==` and `operator<` on `SomeId` also has the correct semantics. For builtins, this is guaranteed, but for user-defined ID types, you can apply the same `std::tie` trick again.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <tuple>

enum { invalid = -1 };
using SomeId = int;   // or any regular type with op== and op<
using SomeData = int; // or any regular type with op== and op<

struct MyFlag
{
    SomeId source_id; // INVALID_ID by default
    SomeData data;    // regular type

    friend bool operator==(MyFlag const& a, MyFlag const& b) 
    { return std::tie(a.source_id, a.data) == std::tie(b.source_id, b.data); }

    friend bool operator!=(MyFlag const& a, MyFlag const& b) 
    { return !(a == b); }

    friend bool operator<(MyFlag const& a, MyFlag const& b) 
    { return std::tie(a.source_id, a.data) < std::tie(b.source_id, b.data); }

    // similarly define >=, >, and <= in terms of !(a < b), (b < a) and !(b < a)

    friend bool id_equal_to(MyFlag const& a, MyFlag const& b)
    { return a.source_id == b.source_id; }    
};

int main()
{    
    auto const id = 0;
    auto const data_A = 1;
    auto const data_B = 2;

    MyFlag flag_a { id, data_A };
    MyFlag flag_b { id, data_B };

    assert( flag_a != flag_b );
    assert( id_equal_to(flag_a, flag_b) );
    assert( flag_a.data != flag_b.data );

    MyFlag flag = flag_b;
    assert( flag != flag_a );
    assert( id_equal_to(flag, flag_a) );
    assert( flag.data != flag_a.data );

    auto const id_x = invalid;
    const MyFlag flag_x = { id_x, data_A };
    flag = flag_x;
    assert( flag != flag_a );
    assert( id_equal_to(flag, flag_x) );
    assert( !id_equal_to(flag, flag_a) );
    assert( flag.data == flag_a.data );    
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5368219b0a254d7).

Comment: Usually that is what I do, but in my use case where I ended up with my initial MyFlag type (I have several), it seems that it would make things complicated. One problem is that the container where objects of these types will be pushed in have to make sure we overwrite the previous state of the same object pushed before. Therefore, I would need the container to have a special check using a specific identification functionn like you provided. But in my case I want to avoid having to force an interface. Maybe it's unavoidable to avoid surprises as you suggest though.

Comment: @Klaim In that case, I would suggest using a container with separate `Key, Value` pair (e.g. `map` or `unordered_map`, so that you can only use `Key` comparison (with `Key==SomeId` in your case, and `Value == SomeData`).

Comment: and then the key would be defined by the container. Which is what I wanted to avoid. :)

Comment: @Klaim I don't quite follow. I mean, if you have a large legacy codebase, then sure. But a database type of storage requires some key, and there is no real reason to integrate all your data in one big MyFlag rather than keep a separate primary key SomeID to which you associate your SomeData.

Comment: It's a blackboard, not a database storage. It's a messaging system if you prefer: you post something on the board and it's public for every other system to see. What I wanted is a generic solution that don't impose what you post to be always associated with a type, the combination of type+value would be enough to allow a lookup from another system. However I started to feel the need -but only for some values- to be able to have part of the value not being the identifier inside the blackboard (which overwrite the whole previous object copy when inserted).

Comment: Now I must also clarify: I now think that indeed it might be too surprising a setup and maybe I should change my blackboard system, but it is a bit problematic because I wanted to be able to just post enum values as events (sometime kept forever, sometime posted only for one update cycle of the system) and just be able to have some cases where the value could contain additional data that can be overwritten. I should post an example of use.